# How to get an ID, on click, from a button in Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, dom-events

I have a button `<button (click)="navToPage2($event)" #button block id="test">Click here</button>`

when I click on it, i want to get the `id` attribute:

```
navToPage2(event) {
    console.log(event.target.attributes);
}
```

The issue i'm having is that if I click on it I get `NamedNodeMap {0: class, length: 1}` with no 'id'

But, if i click right on the edge I get `NamedNodeMap {0: block, 1: id, 2: class, length: 3}` with the `id`

The issue is because of the way this button rendered:

```
<button block="" id="test" class="button button-default button-block">
    <span class="button-inner">Click here</span><ion-button-effect></ion-button-effect>    
</button>
```

The `span` has some padding and if i click outside the `span`, I get the `id`

here is a sample https://codepen.io/patrioticcow/pen/XKzdXv?editors=1010 .Make sure to open the browser console to see the result

Any ideas?

Comment: May I ask why do you need that id? Maybe there's another way to do things, and we avoid hacking too much how Ionic renders things...

Comment: There is another way to accomplish my task. In fact there are a few ways.. I was just curious about this particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already defining the template variable `#button`, so you can actually pass it to get the right element id.

```html
<button (click)="navToPage2($event, button)" #button block="" id="test" class="button button-default button-block">
    <span class="button-inner">Click here</span><ion-button-effect></ion-button-effect>    
</button>
```

And in your method:

```js
navToPage2(event, button) {
    console.log(button.id);
}
```

---

> Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LhRXj6YZod4BLtglvVIF?p=preview) example

Comment: weird, I  see ii working, but not in my codepen example